# LibGDX - Circle texture missing top and right border

Tags: android, libgdx

I packed 20 different Circle textures into an atlas, set MipMapLinearLinear,Linear...

I then render the texture's ingame, and depending on the screen size, sometimes the top and the right are missing.

I also tried 0-64 padding, and nothing seems to make even a difference.

The only solution is to make a Circel texture that is at least 4 pixels away from the border. 60x60 on 64x64 png.

What is making this weird behaviour?

Comment: By padding, you mean the `PaddingX` and `PaddingY` in the `GDX Texture Packer`? Have you also tried checking the `Edge padding` option? I personally don't use MipMap, I haven't yet found it to give any visual or performance benefit, and in some cases it does just give erroneous results so I just stick to Linear Linear. Do you have the same issue without MipMap?

Comment: The MipMap actually smoothes alot the textures at lower resolutions. It doesn't matter what filter there is the circle's are missing pixels top and right- Edge padding is alos checked. Seems like I have to create additional pixels... Fail